# is moodle free from cross site scripting (xss) vulnerability?

Tags: security, xss, moodle

is moodle free from cross site scripting (xss) vulnerability? if yes please let me know how it is fixed. If not what will be the solution?

Comment: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Security

Answer (score 0):

No CMS is completely secure. Moodle is no exception and there are a few known areas where XSS vulnerabilities are present - those vary depending on version and depending on the level of access available to the attacker.

There is no umbrella fix for XSS vulnerabilities. I would advise revising the question.

Answer (score 0):

Moodle takes security very seriously and any report about XSS vulnerability is addressed very quickly. Security fixes are released only in the minor versions (every two months), so if you upgrade yours site regularly you can be sure that your site is not vulnerable.
See also https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Moodle_security_procedures

Do not forget that some capabilities are marked as having XSS risk, by default students do not have any of these capabilities but teachers do. There is a security report about XSS trusted users. You have to trust your teachers in moodle